# averiguar posicion de un elemento en array

Tags: php, array

PHP
tengo el siguiente array

```
$a=array("a","b","c");
```

quiero saber la funcion que me permite averiguar la posicion de "c". que me diga que "c" esta en posicion 2.

Answer (score 2):

Traducida de SO en ingles [Link de la pregunta original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804354/finding-the-position-of-an-element-in-a-simple-array)

Usa [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/array_search) para obtener la clave del valor

```php
$key = array_search("b", $arr);
```

El codigo completo:

```
<?php
$arr=array("a","b","c");
$key = array_search("b", $arr);
print_r($key);
```

La salida seria algo como esto:

```
1
```

Ahora, si deseas obtener las posiciones en el arreglo, puedes buscarla por el index de su clave dentro de tu arreglo asociativo.

```php
$offset = array_search($key, array_keys($arr));
```

Esto ultimo es aplicable a un arreglo como el siguiente:

```
$arr = array('foo' => 10, 'bar' => 45, 'baz' => 23);
```